# Can not import font family

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello everyone one i am trying to import a font family in my flutter project. I downloaded the ttf file and import it in the pubs pubspec.yaml like on the picture. I did pub get and get the following error: expected fonts to either be null or a list like on the picture. I also tried to add many assets but getting another error. I searched on Google about the error but found nothing. Please help me[puspec.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcbzF.jpg)

Comment: Please copy your code in a [code block](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#code-and-syntax-highlighting)

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a space between your dash and `asset` at line 44

YAML is a file format that is layout sensitive (see: https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/yaml-tutorial-everything-you-need-get-started)

Comment: Please click the tick button if the answer seems satisfing to you